# upload file by Chrome File Upload dialog using selenium webdriver in headless mode in python

Tags: selenium, dialog, webdriver, headless

I'm trying to use the selenium chrome driver in headless mode to upload a file to a web, but the web doesn't support the input tags to use `send_key`, it opens a `Chrome` File Upload dialog. I try to use pyautogui to handle keyboard and type the file path in my computer to the dialog, but it just works without headless mode.

**Is there any idea to solve this upload problem?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to try running some Javascript to reveal the `input` element. I've personally run tests in headless mode that perform this exact function with success.

```
# Fetch file input element
fileInput = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@type='file']")

#  Execute Javascript to reveal the element
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].style.display = 'block';", fileInputElement)

# Send keys to file input
fileInput.send_keys("Path/To/File/To/Upload")
```

Once you do this, you can `send_keys` to the hidden element.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/document/d/118Ez5TJTqBNLRU3RFqqHhOOaBnvaquOPGhdZ8D1Rnno/edit

Comment: i'm sorry that i don't know how to use github, i'm just a newbie

Comment: here is the full code https://docs.google.com/document/d/118Ez5TJTqBNLRU3RFqqHhOOaBnvaquOPGhdZ8D1Rnno/edit

Comment: @TăngĐứcThịnh Updated my answer based on the HTML sample you posted.

Comment: amazing, it works, I thought that this can't be done by selenium. Thanks a lot